# How to assign a vector of values to rows selected with the %in% operator

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in the form:

```
X <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
V1 <- c("CHE", "CHE", "CHE", "FRA", "FRA", "FRA", "FRA")
V2 <- c("String1", "String2", "String2", "String1", "String3", "String4", "String3")
V3 <- c("String5", "String5", "String5", "String6", "String6", "String7", "String7")

df <- data.frame(X, V1, V2, V3)
```

How can I select rows based on X with `X %in% c(2, 4, 5)` and then assign a vector of strings across the data frame?

I tried:

```
 df[df$X %in% c(2, 4, 5), c(2:4)] <- c("CHE", "Lago Maggiore", "X")
```

but it doesn't work as expected giving:

```
 X            V1            V2            V3
1           CHE       String1       String5
2           CHE           CHE           CHE
3           CHE       String2       String5
4 Lago Maggiore Lago Maggiore Lago Maggiore
5             X             X             X
6           FRA       String4       String7
7           FRA       String3       String7
```

While the expected result would be:

```
X            V1            V2            V3
1           CHE       String1       String5
2           CHE Lago Maggiore             X
3           CHE       String2       String5
4           CHE Lago Maggiore             X
5           CHE Lago Maggiore             X
6           FRA       String4       String7
7           FRA       String3       String7
```

Comment: can you put your expected result?

Comment: `df <- data.frame(..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: This good old stringsAsFactors ! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the columns are of class "character":

```
df <- data.frame(X, V1, V2, V3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Data.frames are lists of column vectors. If you want to assign to multiple columns, pass a list (or data.frame) instead of a character vector:

```
df[df$X %in% c(2, 4, 5), c(2:4)] <- list("CHE", "Lago Maggiore", "X")

#  X  V1            V2      V3
#1 1 CHE       String1 String5
#2 2 CHE Lago Maggiore       X
#3 3 CHE       String2 String5
#4 4 CHE Lago Maggiore       X
#5 5 CHE Lago Maggiore       X
#6 6 FRA       String4 String7
#7 7 FRA       String3 String7
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `rep` with `each` parameter which varies based on number of rows to filter

```
df[df$X %in% c(2, 4, 5), 2:4] <- rep(c("CHE", "Lago Maggiore", "X"), each = 3)

df
#  X  V1            V2      V3
#1 1 CHE       String1 String5
#2 2 CHE Lago Maggiore       X
#3 3 CHE       String2 String5
#4 4 CHE Lago Maggiore       X
#5 5 CHE Lago Maggiore       X
#6 6 FRA       String4 String7
#7 7 FRA       String3 String7
```

**data**

```
X <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
V1 <- c("CHE", "CHE", "CHE", "FRA", "FRA", "FRA", "FRA")
V2 <- c("String1", "String2", "String2", "String1", "String3", "String4", "String3")
V3 <- c("String5", "String5", "String5", "String6", "String6", "String7", "String7")
df <- data.frame(X, V1, V2, V3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```